# Kelly criterion for betting with multiple return i.e. x times the bet

Tags: probability, gambling

Let's say I have a total bankroll of $1,000.

For a coin toss of 52% and even money back, the bet should be...

$$\begin{align} (0.52 * 2 - 1) * $1,000 = 0.04 * $1,000 = $40 \end{align}$$

**What would the formula look like for a 7% chance of 10 times the bet?**

I am not a mathematician, so please be gentle with the explanation/formula.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a negative number because this is a losing bet and you want to take the other side.  It looks like you get your stake back when you win as you are defining it, so your formula gives $(0.07\cdot 10-1)\cdot 1000=-300$ so you should bet $300$ on the other side.  Read starting with "If the edge is negative" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion).